# Junit not passing even though it should

Tags: java, junit

Updated the isVanityURL method. See below for original question and code based on Shahid's recommendation. Also looking at the Path class as suggested by assylias.

```
public static boolean isVanityPath(String resourcePath) {

    String resPath = resourcePath;

    if (resPath == null) {
        return false;
    } else {

        resPath = resPath.trim();

        if (!resPath.equalsIgnoreCase(StringPool.BLANK)) {

            int len = resPath.length();
            String startChar = resPath.substring(0, 1);

            if (startChar.equals(StringPool.FORWARD_SLASH) && len > 1) {
                resPath = resPath.substring(1, len--);

            }else{
                return false;
            }

            int lastIndexOfSlash = resPath.lastIndexOf(StringPool.FORWARD_SLASH);
            int slashIndex = resPath.indexOf(StringPool.FORWARD_SLASH);

            if (slashIndex != -1)
                return slashIndex == lastIndexOfSlash && lastIndexOfSlash == len - 1;
            else
                return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the updated JUnit Test

```
@Before
public void setUp() {

    vu = Mockito.mock(ResourcePathUtil.class);
}

@Test
public void testVanityURLWhenRoot() {
    Assert.assertFalse(ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath("/"));
}

@Test
public void testVanityURLWhenNull() {
    Assert.assertFalse(ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath(null));
}

@Test
public void testVanityURLWhenValidVanity() {
    Assert.assertTrue(ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath("/vanitycode"));
}

@Test
public void testVanityURLWhenValidVanityWithTrailingSlash() {
    boolean retValue = ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath("/vanitycode/");
    Assert.assertFalse("Returned True", retValue);

}

@Test
public void testVanityURLWhenInvalidVanityWithTrailingSlash() {
    Assert.assertFalse(ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath("/vanitycode/invalidwithslash/"));
}

@Test
public void testVanityURLWhenInvalidVanity() {
    Assert.assertFalse(ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath("/vanitycode/justinvalid"));
}

@Test
public void testVanityURLWhenBlank() {
    Assert.assertFalse(ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath(""));
}
```

I have the following class (ResourcePathUtil) with a static method. I'd like to test it with a JUnit (URLTest). However some of the tests (testVanityURLWhenRoot, testVanityURLWhenValidVanity) don't seem to pass, although it should. Any pointers on what I am doing wrong?

```
public class ResourcePathUtil {

/**
  * 
  * @param url
  * @param data
  * @return result 
  */
public static boolean isVanityPath(String resourcePath) {

    String resPath = resourcePath;

    if (resPath == null) {
        return false;
    } else {

        resPath = resPath.trim();

        if (!resPath.equalsIgnoreCase(StringPool.BLANK)) {

            int len = resPath.length();
            String startChar = resPath.substring(0, 1);

            if (startChar.equals(StringPool.FORWARD_SLASH)) {
                resPath = resPath.substring(1, len--);

            }

            int lastIndexOfSlash = resPath.lastIndexOf(StringPool.FORWARD_SLASH);
            int slashIndex = resPath.indexOf(StringPool.FORWARD_SLASH);

            if (slashIndex != -1)
                return slashIndex == lastIndexOfSlash && lastIndexOfSlash == len - 1;
            else
                return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The JUnit Class is below

```
import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class URLTest {


@Before
public void setUp() {

    vu = Mockito.mock(ResourcePathUtil.class);
}

@Test
public void testVanityURLWhenRoot() {
    Assert.assertFalse(ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath("/"));
}

@Test
public void testVanityURLWhenNull() {
    Assert.assertFalse(ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath(null));
}

@Test
public void testVanityURLWhenValidVanity() {
    Assert.assertTrue(!ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath("/vanitycode"));
}

@Test
public void testVanityURLWhenValidVanityWithTrailingSlash() {
    boolean retValue = ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath("/vanitycode/");
    Assert.assertTrue("Returned False", !retValue);

}

@Test
public void testVanityURLWhenInvalidVanityWithTrailingSlash() {
    Assert.assertFalse(ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath("/vanitycode/invalidwithslash/"));
}

@Test
public void testVanityURLWhenInvalidVanity() {
    Assert.assertFalse(ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath("/vanitycode/justinvalid"));
}

@Test
public void testVanityURLWhenBlank() {
    Assert.assertFalse(ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath(""));
}

}
```

String Pool Class is below

```
public class StringPool {

public static final String BLANK = "";
public static final String FORWARD_SLASH = "/";

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `Path` class?

Comment: Which test case fails? All of them?

Comment: @assylias, do you mean [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)

Comment: *"Junit not passing even though it should"* - ha! The sooner you abandon this mindset and learn to use the debugger, the better.

Comment: @kryger, You are right. I should have said that I wasn't sure why it was failing.

Comment: @Pragrammer yup, that one.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void testVanityURLWhenRoot() {
    // expecting isVanityPath() to return false
    Assert.assertFalse(ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath("/"));
}

@Test
public void testVanityURLWhenValidVanity() {
    // expecting isVanityPath() to return false
    Assert.assertTrue(!ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath("/vanitycode"));
}
```

In both `testVanityURLWhenRoot` and `testVanityURLWhenValidVanity`, you are expecting `false`. But you are getting `true`. The reason lies in the method `isVanityPath()`.

In both cases, **the value of `slashIndex` is -1**. And you are returning `true` when slashIndex is equal to -1. That's why in both cases you are getting `true` result, though you are expecting `false`.

```
if (slashIndex != -1) {
    return slashIndex == lastIndexOfSlash && lastIndexOfSlash == len - 1;
} else { // it executes when slashIndex == -1
    return true;
}
```

**Suggestion:**

Instead of:

```
Assert.assertTrue(!ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath("/vanitycode"));
```

write:

```
Assert.assertFalse(ResourcePathUtil.isVanityPath("/vanitycode"));
```

The latter is more readable.

Comment: Thanks fixed testVanityURLWhenRoot, and  testVanityURLWhenValidVanity , in the isVanityURL method. Now facing an issue with the testVanityURLWhenValidVanityWithTrailingSlash.